# Production time optimization model

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization

I have a problem where I have 2 different types of raw-material. These materials can be processed in two different production-lines which take different amount of time, depending on raw material. After the production lines, I have a worker that needs around 5 minutes to pack the finished product. He can only process one finished product at a time, and there is no place for a queue. I'm looking for a model that can decide at which times I need to put the raw material into the process-line to that the worker gets a finished product every 5 minutes.

I'm looking for a finished or similar optimization models. Does anyone recognize this problem and can supply me with an model, or can you maybe recommend me some papers.

Thank you!

Comment: How long does it take each product to go through its production line?

Comment: Is there a separate line for each type of raw material, or can each line handle both materials?

Comment: The production-line is slow, the process takes somewhere between 20-60 minutes. Each line can handle both materials!

Comment: The original problem is rather big and I have made a few simplifications in the first post.

Comment: Use @Username to notify people that you have answered their comment, otherwise they won't know. When you say the process takes between 20-60 minutes, does that mean it can vary that much for a given material on a given line? Or do you know exactly how long it takes for each material on each line?

Comment: I'm missing something about this problem, I'm sure.  Since you can't hope to package more than one job every $5$ minutes, why not place a job in production every $5$ minutes (or a little more, in case the worker packaging worker falls a bit behind.)  I don't see the advantage of using both lines from the given information.